# Get different element from 2 arrays with different attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

My situation:
I have these 2 arrays

```
allElem=[ {key: "a1234c", name: "username@gmail.com"}, {key: "b6789d", name: 
 username2@gmail.com"},{key: "ab234s", name: "toretrieve@gmail.com"}]

otherElem=[{key: "a1234c", name: "username@gmail.com", newAtt: 1}, {key: "b6789d", 
name: "username2@gmail.com",  newAtt: 2}]
```

As you can see the arrays have different structure and I want to return the ekement of the first array:{key: "ab234s", name: "toretrieve@gmail.com"}

I tried to use filter like this:

```
var filtered= allElem.filter((elem: { key: any; }) => !otherElem.find(({ key }) 
=> elem.key === key));
```

but is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need:

```
interface Item {
    key: string;
    name: string;
    newAtt?: number;
}

const allElem: Item[] = [{key: "a1234c", name: "username@gmail.com"}, {key: "b6789d", name: "username2@gmail.com"}, {key: "ab234s", name: "toretrieve@gmail.com"}];

const otherElem: Item[] = [{key: "a1234c", name: "username@gmail.com", newAtt: 1}, {key: "b6789d", name: "username2@gmail.com",  newAtt: 2}];

const filtered = allElem.filter((itemFromAll: Item) => !otherElem.find((itemFromOther: Item) => itemFromAll.key === itemFromOther.key));
```

I would suggest you to read about types in TypeScript. There are some useful links:

- Basic TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html
- Build-in types and basic types information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html
- Advanced level for future: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html